# Wi-Fi won't allow Ubuntu Software

Tags: networking, wireless, software-center

I have just installed Ubuntu software.And the problem I'm currently having is my college wi-fi is censored and I am unable to use my Ubuntu Software.When I am Using a browser the network requires me to input my credentials so that it may work.Ubuntu Software doesn't require this and therefore cant work.Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: If you only require to install one or a few packages, you can install manually. Find them online, download them to your desktop, and then install. You can also find packages here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu I can provide more details later.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider.

1. When you log onto your college wifi, does it open a webpage where you can input your credentials? Try opening a webpage on firefox or chrome to see if there is a login webpage.
2. I've run into the problem where my school wifi says it does not support my Linux distro, but then I just open a new tab and the internet works fine. Try that, if you can open and login to the network via a login webpage.
3. If all else fails, contact your college's computing/network help desk, they probably know the most about making the wifi accessible to linux users.

Good luck!